# Hibernate Envers modified flag behavior

Tags: hibernate-envers

I use Hibernate with Envers and have an entity with some columns annotated with `@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)`, i.e. there is an additional boolean column in the _AUD table that indicates if the column was updated or not.

If I save a new entity, a corresponding entry is written in the _AUD table with revtype 0. I have a problem with the _MOD colum value. If the column is null the value of the _MOD entry is false and if there is a non-null value the _MOD entry is true. I think for a new entry (i.e. revtype=0) it's more logical to have *all* _MOD values set to false since the columns haven't been modified. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason those `_MOD` fields end up being set for values that are inserted initially is because all of the prior entity state is *null* and those comparisons yield differences (e.g. non-null != null) and therefore its seen as having been modified.  The feature does not take into account whether the operation being performed is an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or a `DELETE`.

Personally, I find the current behavior more logical.

For that initial `ADD` operation, changing the behavior will force you to have some branch logic to deal with *seed value* changes based on revision number of revision type where-as simply using the `_MOD` field behavior as it is today implies you can simply ignore the revision type/number and just use the toggles on any query.

Unfortunately you cannot toggle this behavior presently.

We could look at adding a configuration parameter that would allow you to influence whether the `ADD` operation should be treated as a modification or not.  If its something that you and others find useful, please feel free to open a JIRA [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net).